# Multi-line texts overlaps in comment window

Tags: discussion, support, bug

Today I was typing a comment to reply a user. However, when I was typing my comment, I saw that -- with (might be due to) the new-interface -- overlapping texts which makes it hard to read (all of a sudden).

[image]

Is it a know issue? Because, this is the first time I am encountering this.

I use `Windows 7` with the `Chrome version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.

**Update 1:** From `@Inquisitive Lurker's` comment, it can be seen that this issue has also been reproduced with `Linux Mint 18.3 and Chrome 71.0.3578.98`. No external add-ons.

[image]

Comment: You may want to add your OS and browser. On my system (Firefox 64.0 [64! - there used to be a time, not too long ago, when Firefox versions were in the single digits] and Win 10) the 'p' and 'f' don't quite clash. But I think the font stack fallback could mean that I see a different font than you.

Comment: @moewe Thanks, I have updated it.

Comment: @moewe Sorry my  bad, I forgot to type the browser name.

Comment: This is what it looks like for me using firefox on mac: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmzwU.png

Comment: @samcarter interesting :D

Comment: @Raaja Is the problem still visible if you post the comment?

Comment: @samcarter not when I post a comment. Only when I type a comment.

Comment: @Raaja Indeed interesting :)

Comment: @Raaja: No problem here on Windows 10 (same version of Chrome): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le1CG.png

Comment: @Werner things just getting better and better ;)

Comment: Maybe you use a zoom level other than 100%? StackExchange uses responsive design, so they don't support zooming (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296008) - and if you still zoom it is at your own risk and anything can happen.

Comment: @Marijn I don't zoom, it is in fact always at 100%. However, I extend my laptop monitor into a bigger screen. I'm not sure whether that would cause a problem. Because, both screens have the same aspect ratio at the least.

Comment: Reproduced on Linux Mint 18.3 in Chrome 71.0.3578.98: [(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnnrW.png). No zoom or extensions (edit: except some anti-tracking ones, but I'll try again without), but I *have* changed the default "standard font" to Symbola (I don't remember what it was originally).

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker Nice! Also, in my case, the fonts haven't been influenced :D I have added that picture as an update in my answer.

Comment: I've rechecked, this time with every single extension disabled - still happens. Also, just to clarify: that Symbola thing is just a Chrome setting, it doesn't look like it actually affects comments here - they still seem to be in Arial/Helvetica/whatever this is. So it's probably just a red herring.

Comment: One last [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3ZLX.png) - this time with both Chrome and Firefox (again, default installation, no extensions). However, looking at it closely, the text is not actually overlapping - it's just that there's absolutely no space in-between the two letters. In any case, I'm not really bothered by this - might not even have noticed without this question - so I don't plan on investigating further.

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker Thanks for the updates :)